# is a try catch acceptable at a mapchange scenario

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I sure read the other posts of try catch performance here but i am not sure if it's fine if i use it in my point.
I am using it at some points of my gameLoop. 
At first. I am using libgdx the `Stage and Actor` system. But when i change the map clear the Stage it does sometimes thow `NullPointerException` at the stage.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:48)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:166)
at com.portaaenigma.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:91)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

So i added a simple try catch because i cant handle it in any other way. I tried it with a status and do change the status to something else while changing the map and clearing the stage and adding new monsters. But it actually does the same error. The try catch looks like this:

```
    if (this.status == GameStatus.GAME) {
        try {
            this.figureStage.act(); // figures act <-- this is line 91
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // catching nullpointer at mapchange
            Gdx.app.log(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Nullpointer catched at mapswitch: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am a bit confused if this is okay because i looks to me more or less like a "fix it" solution. It does work without any issues. Sure it does throw sometimes when i change the map but i dont get why.
I also need to add a try catch at the lookup method at my monsters. If i get into the mapchange while it does thow out of bounds at my collision detection at the monsters.

okay the general question is, if this is a solution that is acceptable or if there should be a way better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right.  This is a hack.  The hack may be good to help you make progress, but at some point you need to figure out what causes your NPE.

Read the stack, find the line with the NPE, figure out which pointer is null, then either find a way to prevent it from being null or add a branch to prevent that code from running.

One trick that may help if to use a valid object in place of null where possible.  For example, if you are looking up a person who does not exist, return a NOBODY object (that you define yourself) instead of null.  Override all your selectors (get methods) with neutral values.

Comment: Yea i thought so. But i didn't get it save from that. I am confused how it even can happen. The character calls the change Map method if he collides with a mapchange field. In that case i do save my old monsters and clear the stage that does iterate oveer all of my actors. While that the render tries to act what cant be possible. I really dont get it ... Id post that but its a bit "more"

Comment: Take a look at Group.java, line 48.  That line is expecting some value to be filled in.  Find the value there, then find the place in your code where it should be filled in (more rarely, you have filled the value in correctly and the bug is in the library, but don't make that your first guess)

Comment: I poked around at the library you referenced, and the NOBODY trick won't work for you here, but keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: its a great tip i guess. The confusing thing is that normaly at that point it wouldnt be possible that they act because they are deleted befor they are acting. i found the misstake i guess! The act iterate over all elements. Without caring of if the change startes. After oine full cycle it does care about it so i need to break at all elements